# How can i delete an element in an array and then shift the array in Shell Script?

Tags: bash, shell

First let me state my problem clearly:

Ex: Let's pretend this is my array, (the elements don't matter as in my actual code they vary):

```
array=(jim 0 26 chris billy 78 hello foo bar)
```

Now say I want to remove the following elements:

```
chris 78 hello
```

So I did: `unset array[$i]` while looping through the array.
This removes the elements correctly, however, i end up with an array that looks like this:

```
array=(jim 0 26 '' billy '' '' foo bar)
```

I need it to look like this:

```
array=(jim 0 26 billy foo bar)
```

where *jim* is at index *0*, *0@1*, *26@2*, etc..

How do I delete the elements in the array and move the other elements so that there are no null/empty spaces in the array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ array=( "one two" "three four" "five six" )
$ unset array[1]
$ array=( "${array[@]}" )
$ echo ${array[0]}
one two
$ echo ${array[1]}
five six
```

Shell arrays aren't really intended as data structures that you can add and remove items from (they are mainly intended to provide a second level of quoting for situations like

```
arr=( "one two" "three four" )
somecommand "${arr[@]}"
```

to provide `somecommand` with two, not four, arguments). But this should work in most situations.

Comment: Sorry I am a bit late in marking this as correct.  It helped me out.  thanks.

Answer (score 4):

See http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial

10. Remove an Element from an Array

...

```
Unix=('Debian' 'Red hat' 'Ubuntu' 'Suse' 'Fedora' 'UTS' 'OpenLinux');

pos=3

Unix=(${Unix[@]:0:$pos} ${Unix[@]:$(($pos + 1))})
```

This contracts the array around pos, which the original poster wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
user@pc:~$ array=(jim 0 26 chris billy 78 hello foo bar)
user@pc:~$ for itm2rm in chris 78 hello; do array=(\`echo ${array[@]} | sed "s/\<${itm2rm}\>//g"\`); done ; echo ${array[@]}
jim 0 26 billy foo bar
```

Answer (score 0):

this post had been revised and moved to its own post as a more in-depth tutorial [how to remove an array element correctly in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736756/how-to-remove-an-array-element-correctly-in-a-for-loop)