# remove an item from a list/variable - Bash

Tags: linux, bash

If I call a variable as a list of files:

files=$(ls *.txt)

I then want to remove the first item (file) in the list

Thanks

Clive

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17533231/3776858

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never parse the output of `ls`; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

Fortunately, in your case you're not actually using any of `ls`'s functionality; Bash already handles the `*.txt` part, so the `ls` is pretty redundant.

You can write this:

```
# Set files to an array of the files with names ending in '*.txt':
files=(*.txt)

# Set files to an array consisting of ${files[1]}, ${files[2]}, ...:
files=("${files[@]:1}")
```

(See [the *Bash Reference Manual*, § 3.5.3 "Shell Parameter Expansion"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion); search for `${parameter:offset}`.)

Comment: And a couple other useful tips....
[[ 1. To remove the last one: `rm ${files[@]:(-1)}` ]]
[[ 2.  To remove a range  `rm ${files[@]:1:3}` ]]  
Note the latter removes the second, third, and fourth matches.

Also for very old BASH versions, the `-1` to call out the last element of the array will not work.

Comment: Hi, I really don't understand what this is doing; 'files=(*.txt)' gives me only one file '1stFile.txt' when I issue 'echo $files'. Then when I issue 'rm "${files[0]}"' then 'echo $files' I'm left with the same one file. I'm confused.

Comment: Actually, 'files=(*.txt)' leaves me with ' *.txt' when I issue 'echo $files'. The above is what happens when I issue 'files=$(ls *.txt). It doesn't work.

Comment: Wow, what actually happened is I deleted my files by issuing these commands - WTF!

Comment: @user3329732: Eep, I'm sorry. That is what the `rm` ("remove") command does, and it's what I thought you wanted to do. (I wasn't 100% sure, which is why I included the code comment saying that it deletes the file, but given the risk of data loss if it's *not* what you meant, I really should have been more explicit about my uncertainty. I'm sorry. :-/ )

Comment: It's OK I can recreate the files easily. What I want to know is if after I call 'files=$(ls *.txt)' and therefore: files="file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt", how do I then make files="file2.txt file3.txt" (remember 'files=(*.txt)' doesn't work). Thanks

Comment: @user3329732: OK, whew. I've updated my answer with code that will set `files` to the array consisting of `file2.txt` and `file3.txt`. If you want to concatenate the results into a string afterward, you can write `files="${files[*]}"`, though I don't think that's really a good idea. (Arrays are safer for most purposes than space-separated strings.)

Comment: OK thanks for your efforts but it doesn't work. files=(*.txt) does not give a list of files: 'echo $files' only gives 'file1.txt' NOT 'file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt'. The after 'files=("${files[@]:1}")' if I type 'for f in $files: do echo $f; done' I get 'file2.txt' NOT 'file2.txt; file3.txt'

Comment: @user3329732: When `files` is an array, `$files` expands to just the first element. Instead of `for f in $files`, you should write `for f in "${files[@]}"`.

Comment: Thank you so much, and, in particular, thanks for your patience